# Algorithm to generate a random number? Don't use System.Random

Tags: c#, java, .net, random

Had there been no System.Random class, how would have you generated a random number?

Are there any known algorithms or have you guys ever designed one?

Comment: @Dimitar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462219/xkcd-random-number

Comment: may be you should read this and try to create one solution [Random number generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation)

Comment: The Mersenne Twister is a very good option (it has a large period). There are other available and sample code is available if you Google for them. These include Knuth Subtractive, RANLUX, Trustworthe and ZiffGFSR4, among others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

True random numbers can only be generated "outside" a computer, using radioactivity counts and such.  Some VIA processors have hardware to do so.

Volume two of The Art of Computer Programming by Don Knuth spends a lot of time discussing exhaustively various pseudo-random number implementations from a mathematical background.  Recommended reading.

Comment: +1 you can't get a real random number via any programming language.

Comment: Via any _deterministic_ programming language. But many aren't, in fact. E.g. create two threads, and let them race to a mutex. You get less than one bit of entropy that way, but it is really random.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really generate a truly random number with our current deterministic computers. There are, however, many different ways to generate pseudorandom numbers. See [pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) on wikipedia for some information on the algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister). I belive this is the same algorithm implemented by System.Random, it is very common non cryptographically secure PRNG with a good random distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers say, its not possible to generate true random numbers with a computer, but as for pseudo-random, one algorithm that I've used before is the [Linear Congruential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), its simple and fast, but I'm sure there are much better alternatives.

Edit: Grammar